# How to run Karate from java application not from JUnit test

Tags: karate

I managed to run Karate tests using Junit. But what I want is to run Karate from java application instead of Junit runner.

Currently I'am running from JUnit:

```
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateStats;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class TestParallel {

@Test
public void testParallel() {
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports");
    assertTrue("scenarios failed", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
}
}
```

I tried calling the Junit class from my application main using the code below:

```
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = junit.run(TestParallel.class);
```

But I have this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/karate/cucumber/CucumberRunner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the test scope from the karate dependencies in the pom.

Everything works fine including the reports and the output.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please use the Java API, documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api

Note that you won't get reports if you go down this path.